# Powershell syntax to use where condition with a foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and have been practicing to get better so would greatly appreciate all your help.

I have a txt file with just a list of servers that I need to add an account to. However, I need to exclude the server names that does not contain "-" in the servername.

This is what I have right now which obviously doesn't work and I keep getting errors.

```
    $servers = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\SQLServers.txt"
    

     foreach ($server in $servers| Where $server -contains "*-*" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a wildcard string comparison, you'll want the `-like` operator, and then refer to the current pipeline item being tested by `Where-Object` with `$_`:

```
foreach ($server in $servers |Where { $_ -like "*-*" }) {
   # work with each matching $server here
}
```

---

`-like` can also be used to *filter* a collection of strings directly, so in your case you could do:

```
foreach ($server in @($servers) -like "*-*") {
   # work with each matching $server here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Tried the second option and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @afzzaps, if this is the best answer to your question, please select the check mark icon to the left of the answer. That lets others know that this is the best answer. That is how SO works.

Comment: @Mathias, one last item I stumbled upon and if you could help too. After filtering out the $server in $servers -like *-*; I need to find out which of these servers doesn't start with TPP. How can I add that additional filter along with the *-* filter ?

Comment: @afzzaps You can either chain multiple calls to `Where-Object`: `... |Where { $_ -like "*-*"} |Where {$_ -notlike "TPP*"}`, or combine multiple comparisons into a single clause with the `-and` operator: `... |Where { $_ -like "*-*" -and $_ -notlike "TPP*" }`. You could also chain multiple filter comparisons (although it might not be super readable/obvious): `@(@($servers) -like "*-*") -notlike "TPP*"`

Answer (score 0):

If your file have only one column you can use import csv and directly set the name of one and uniq colum, like this :

```
Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\SQLServers.txt" -Header server | where server -Like "*-*" | foreach{

#user serveur name here
$_.Server

}
```

Otherwise you can directly filter on $_ variable like this :

```
Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\SQLServers.txt" | where {$_ -like "*-*"} | foreach{

#user serveur name here
$_

}
```